Query to delete records with lower eff_date in a large table with 400 million records
I have a table with below structure:
create table TEST_TAB
(
  activity_type CHAR(1),
  tracking_code NUMBER,
  eff_date      DATE
)

Sample data for this table:
insert into TEST_TAB (activity_type, tracking_code, eff_date)
values ('A', 1, to_date('01-11-2020', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into TEST_TAB (activity_type, tracking_code, eff_date)
values ('A', 1, to_date('02-01-2024', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into TEST_TAB (activity_type, tracking_code, eff_date)
values ('B', 2, to_date('01-08-2023', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into TEST_TAB (activity_type, tracking_code, eff_date)
values ('B', 2, to_date('02-08-2023', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into TEST_TAB (activity_type, tracking_code, eff_date)
values ('B', 2, to_date('03-08-2023', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));

This is just a sample data and the amount of real data in the original table is nearly 400 million records. What I need to do is that for each group of activity_type, tracking_code, I need to keep the record which has the highest "eff_date" and delete the rest. So for the activity_type=A and tracking_code = 1 I need to keep the one with eff_date = 1/2/2024 and delete the other one.
What I have for now is below query:
delete from test_tab
 where rowid in (select rid
                   from (select rowid as rid,
                                row_number() over(partition by activity_type, tracking_code order by eff_date desc) as row_num
                           from test_tab
                           )
                  where row_num > 1
                  )

However this seems very slow. Could you suggest any better solution?
The original table is partitioned on eff_date and it has index on the rest two columns.
Another point is that there might be more than one year gap between eff_dates of each record in a single group.
Thanks in advance

Do you believe a majority of the table will be deleted, i.e. most (activity_type, tracking_code) combinations have multiple eff_dates?

Half of the table will be deleted

Since you plan on deleting at least half the table anyway, it may be simpler and quicker to just insert the rows you want to keep into a new table, drop the old table, and then rename the new table after. Then you can simplify the query to just a single GROUP BY operation without any joins like so:
CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB2
AS
(
    SELECT
        activity_type,
        tracking_code,
        MAX(eff_date) AS eff_date
    FROM TEST_TAB
    GROUP BY activity_type, tracking_code
);

Since you already have an index on (activity_type, tracking_code) then this above query should be SARGable and performant.

Creating a new table is definitely the right way. I'm just thinking if we could help the optimizer somehow, since the table is partitioned by eff_date. A linear full table scan would probably be faster than a combined index lookup, if we have to read half of the table anyway. - But I'm probably overthinking this and good stats should be enough for the optimizer to choose the right strategy...
